# Check whether TCP connection is possible, when subnet masks are different

Tags: c#, networking, tcp, ipv4, subnet

I have UDP-based network discovery function, which returns the list of devices connected to the host. Every item of this list contains the following information:

```
Host IP address.
Host subnet mask.
Device IP address.
Device IP mask.
```

For every such item I need to detect, whether TCP connection between host and device is possible. Device is running a TCP server. Host needs to connect using TCP client. I know, how to implement this in the case, when host and device subnet masks are the same. But what to do if IP masks are different?

I use C# to show the code, though programming language is not important:

```
bool CanConnect(IPAddress hostIpAddress, IPAddress hostSubnetMask, 
                IPAddress deviceIpAddress, IPAddress deviceSubnetMask)
{
     if ( hostMask.Equals(deviceMask) )
     {
          // I know what to do here. For example, mask is 255.255.255.0
          // hostIpAddress 192.168.1.1, deviceIpAddress 192.168.1.2: TRUE
          // hostIpAddress 192.168.1.1, deviceIpAddress 192.168.2.2: FALSE
     }
     else
     {
          // What to do here, for example, if
          // hostSubnetMask = 255.0.0.0 and deviceSubnetMask = 255.255.255.0
     }
}
```

Of course, I need to detect this without actually trying to make TCP connection.

Comment: Routers route packets between networks. Simply try to open a TCP connection. You should get back an ICMP error if the destination is unreachable for some reason. Also, TCP knows nothing about clients or servers, that is an application concept. TCP creates connections between two peers.

Comment: You cannot do it without establishing a TCP connection. First, IP address and subnet mask have nothing to do with TCP connectivity as they are only about IP routing aspects (that is a fact whether an IP packet can be delivered to a target). Second, even this information doesn't help you to determine whether the routing is possible as routing tables are maintained by routing parties and only this information (routing tables) has influence on an IP packet delivery, while IP address is used by router to determine the next hop by comparing it against the routing tables info.